# tikz overlapping-like underbrace overbrace

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I would like to get the following picture, but avoiding the manual try and error for positioning the lines. Before using TikZ, I tried using LaTeX underbrace and overbrace, but I did not succeed since:
1. my underbrace and overbrace have an "intersecting scope",
2. I dont want a "brace" shape, but the one I use in the current picture.

```
\documentclass{book}    
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\reg}[1]{\textnormal{`}#1\textnormal{'}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[anchor=west] {$\reg{>><}$};
\draw[rounded corners=1pt] (0.27,-0.1) -- (0.27,-0.2) -- (0.82,-0.2) -- (0.82,-0.1);
\draw[rounded corners=1pt] (0.9,-0.1) -- (0.9,-0.2) -- (1.2,-0.2) -- (1.2,-0.1);
\draw[rounded corners=1pt] (0.58,0.08) -- (0.58,0.18) -- (1.2,0.18) -- (1.2,0.08);
\end{tikzpicture}   

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is a Ti*k*Z question, I provide a Ti*k*Z answer, i.e. do not play with `\rlap` and the like. I'd use `tikzmark` for this, then.

```
\documentclass{book}    
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\newcommand{\reg}[1]{\textnormal{`}#1\textnormal{'}}

\begin{document}
$\reg{\tikzmarknode{n1}{>}\tikzmarknode{n2}{>}\tikzmarknode{n3}{<}}$
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\draw[rounded corners=1pt] ([yshift=-0.5pt,xshift=0.85pt]n1.south west)
-- ++ (0,-0.1) -| ([yshift=-0.5pt,xshift=-0.85pt]n2.south east);
\draw[rounded corners=1pt] ([yshift=-0.5pt,xshift=0.85pt]n3.south west)
-- ++ (0,-0.1) -| ([yshift=-0.5pt,xshift=-0.85pt]n3.south east);
\draw[rounded corners=1pt] ([yshift=0.5pt,xshift=0.85pt]n2.north west)
-- ++ (0,0.1) -| ([yshift=0.5pt,xshift=-0.85pt]n3.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}   
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I get an "! Undefined control sequence. <argument> \tikzmarknode ..." on line 22 when compiling the answer with a one year old LaTeX distribution on the mac.

Comment: @NicolasBeldiceanu When was the last time you updated your TeX distribution? `\tikzmarknode` has only been added very recently, so I guess you have an older version.

Comment: Summer 2017 I think, but I will take the latest distribution.